# ASP.NET HTML.BeginForm/Url.Action Url points to itself

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform, url.action

I facing an issue with the ASP.NET `BeginForm` helper.

I try to create a form that should point to `/Project/Delete` and I tried the following statemant to reach this target:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Project"))
{
}

<form action="@Url.Action("Delete", "Project")"></form>
```

But unfortunately both rendered actions points to `/Projects/Delete/LocalSqlServer`, which is the url of site called in the browser

```
<form action="/Project/Delete/LocalSqlServer" method="post"></form>
```

I really dont know why the rendered action points to itself instead of the given route.I already read all posts (which I found) on google and SO, but found no solution.

This is the only route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this are my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    return View(new DeleteViewModel { Name = id });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(DeleteViewModel model)
{
    _configService.DeleteConnectionString(model);
    return null;
}
```

I am using .NET 4.6.2.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks
Sandro

Comment: I ran into something similar a little bit ago, will see if I can find the github issue for you.

Comment: Could you show us Delete action method?

Comment: You need to show your route definitions and both the `[HttGet]` and `[httpPost]` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truth is, it is a bug in asp.net but they refuse to acknowledge it as a bug and just call it a "feature".  But, here is how you deal with it...

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
// gets the form page
[HttpGet, Route("testing/MyForm/{code}")]  
public IActionResult MyForm(string code)
{
    return View();
}

// process the form submit
[HttpPost, Route("testing/MyForm")]
public IActionResult MyForm(FormVM request)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

So in my case, the `code` would get appended just like you are getting with the `LocalSqlServer`.

Here are both versions of how you make a basic asp form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("myform", "testing", new {code = "" }))
{
    <input type="text" value="123" />
}


<form id="theId" asp-controller="testing" asp-action="myform" asp-route-id="" asp-route-code="">
    <input type="text" value="asdf" />

</form>
```

In the stop where I put `asp-route-code`, the "code" needs to match the variable in the controller.  Same for `new {code = "" }`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution works perfect for me, thank you @nurdyguy.