# window.location not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

Hey I have a really weird issue I can't figure out.....

Basically I have a method inside my controller that returns a view based on what a value of a id you pass it.

The front end

```
window.location = '<%=Url.Action("PaymentTool", "PaymentHistory") %>' + '/' + profile.id;
```

and the back end

```
public ActionResult PaymentTool(string username, int? profileID)
```

Now this works great for the first time running. However whenever I run it a second time without refreshing the page I am getting an issue.

I have logged it out to confirm this and it seems like

`'<%=Url.Action("PaymentTool", "PaymentHistory") %>'`

is holding the old value and adding the new value onto it ending with a url of e.g

`PaymentHistory/PaymentTool/123/1234`

when the correct working url would be

`PaymentHistory/PaymentTool/1234`.

I have logged out the profile.id and this is a single number each time and is not storing the old value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this seems like a very weird bug to me.

Comment: With so little code we can only speculate and guess. Show more code and help us reproduce the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at your URL and truncate anything after `PaymentTool/` before adding the ID in.

Comment: The stuff between `<%` and `%>` is server-side code which will be evaluated when you visit the server and then written to the client.  So, if you "run it a second time without refreshing the page", you are not visiting the server and this will not change.

Comment: This is probably related to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577865/asp-net-html-beginform-url-action-url-points-to-itself/45578740?noredirect=1#comment78125941_45578740

Comment: Thank you nurdyguy... That was it! Thank ye all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a really annoying bug that MS calls a "feature"...  If you have a route attribute then you need to use this:

```
Url.Action("myform", "testing", new { code = "" }
```

where `code` is whatever the name of the route attribute variable is in the controller.  You'll then have to play with it a bit to create your new route.